# How to write my code in dojo

Tags: dojo, target

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {

     var popup = $("#searchProductContainer");
     var address_popup = $('#widget_deliveryLoc_Content')
     if (!$('#headerSearchList').is(e.target) && !popup.is(e.target) && popup.has(e.target).length == 0 ) {
         popup.hide();
     }
     if(!$('#widget_deliveryLoc_position').is(e.target) && !address_popup.is(e.target) && address_popup.has(e.target).length == 0){
        address_popup.hide();
     }

 });
```

Comment: Sorry, but at the moment the question is not likely to be answered here. SO is not a write-my-code automaton ;). What have you tried, where are you stuck (and why do you want to rewrite in dojo anyway?)

Comment: can some on help me in this?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, this above jquery code is working fine now,
But i want to change this to dojo, i tried e.target is not getting my id

Answer (score 1):

Open your browser console(better result in chrome) and print object e in console.log then check its structure and analyze why you are not getting your id.